# Interpolation Scipy Python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I try to use scipy.interpolate.interp2d but I have a problem.

This is my code :

```
import scipy.interpolate as itp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z_srtrm = 100 * np.random.rand(4,4)
x_srtrm = np.arange(0,4)
y_srtrm = np.arange(0,4)

I = itp.interp2d(x_srtrm,y_srtrm,z_srtrm,kind='cubic') 
xi = np.linspace(0,4,100) 
yi = np.linspace(0,4,100) 
Z = I(xi,yi) 

zx = np.arange(0,100)
zy = np.arange(0,100)

I_inv = itp.interp2d(zx,zy,Z,kind='cubic') 
xj = np.linspace(0,100,4) 
yj = np.linspace(0,100,4) 
z = I_inv(xj,yj)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,1)
ax1.imshow(z_srtrm)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,2)
ax2.imshow(Z)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,3,3)
ax3.imshow(z)

plt.show()
```

Normally, z_srtm should be equal to z, but it is not the case.
Can you explain me why ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason are off-by-one errors stemming from how `np.arange` works:

```py
>>> np.arange(0, 10)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

There are two changes you need to make. First, `x_srtrm` and `y_srtrm` go from 0 to 3, so you need to maintain that when upsampling:

```py
I = itp.interp2d(x_srtrm, y_srtrm, z_srtrm, kind='cubic') 
xi = np.linspace(0, 3, 100) 
yi = np.linspace(0, 3, 100)
Z = I(xi, yi)
```

Second, `zx` and `zy` go from 0 to 99, so you need to account for it when downsampling:

```py
I_inv = itp.interp2d(zx, zy, Z, kind='cubic') 
xj = np.linspace(0, 99, 4)
yj = np.linspace(0, 99, 4)
z = I_inv(xj, yj)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, it  works. Yes I totally understand what you explained !

Comment: Glad I could help!